# Polish characters in php mysql web app

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, special-characters

My php / mysql application is trying to INSERT the following into a varchar field:

ł

..however my data in table is stored as:

& #322;

Is this something I have to handle in php or mysql?

Any advice appreciated greatly.

Thanks Paul

Further information - the data is user input, typed into a textbox and then the value of that then inserted into mysql.

Updated: Code

```
   function addNewCustomer($data, $aid){
      $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT MAX(CustomerID) FROM tbl001_Customer"));

      $query = "INSERT INTO tbl001_Customer
                (CustomerID,CustomerName,Country,Address1,Address2,Address3,Address4,Postcode,PhoneNumber)
                VALUES ('".str_pad($row[0]+1,5,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT)."','{$data['quote_customer_name']}','{$data['quotecountry']}',
                        '{$data['quote_address1']}','{$data['quote_address2']}','{$data['quote_town_city']}',
                        '{$data['quote_country']}','{$data['quote_postcode']}','{$data['quote_primary_phoneno']}')";
        if (!mysql_query($query)) {
            $isError = true;
            echo mysql_error();
        }
```

Comment: Where does the data originated? Looks to me, as if it is encoded there.

Comment: It appears the htmlentities() has been called here. Do you have some code? Mysql wouldn't convert it like this. If you want to store Polish characters without encoding etc, you need to check the character set of the table in mysql.

Comment: If we dont see some code we cant see where the encoding is coming from. However, converting it to an HTML entity is not such a bad idea, because this will always be saved correctly and can be used directly when outputting.

Comment: CustomerID creation is just amazing. that's all i can say, because there is nothing relevant in the code to the encoding problem.

Comment: The field I am having issues with is when inserting "CustomerName".

Comment: there is no code relevant to the field named "CustomerName" and encoding issue

Comment: yes there is! upon INSERT to the db, if you use the character "ł" as value for "$data['quote_customer_name", then issue occurs. Just to reiterate the value "& #322" is saved to mysql instead of "ł".

Answer (score 0):

This is something you should NOT handle in php.
You are calling `htmlentities()` function somewhere, which is absolutely useless one.

So, just get rid of this function call and have your data untouched.

For the filtering user input against XSS injections you have to use `htmlspecialchars()` function.

Comment: Hey, I just searched my project for "htmlentities()" and got no results therefore I am not using it.

Comment: that's quite strange. try to debug a little. there is some code between the form and the database, you know. just try to print out your data in the several places, and try to spot the place where it got changed.

Answer (score -1):

Make use of html_encode() before inserting in the database, after selecting from database use html_decode() the data.

Comment: will html_encode() save "ł" instead of "& #322;" into the database?

Comment: yeah only not in that exact sign.